# arcgis 10.3.1 crashes when trying to click on raster properties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to open the properties of a raster dataset, however Arcgis 10.3.1 crashes every time I try to click on raster properties. This happens in ArcCatalog and in ArcMap, and with any raster dataset saved in either a geodatabase and folder.

I've had 10.3.1 for two months though haven't worked with raster datasets until now. I never had this issue with previous versions of ArcGIS

A google search found me this link https://geonet.esri.com/thread/172145 where someone had the same problem but there's no resolution.

What else should I try to fix this frustrating situation?

Comment: If you have not already done so I would perform an uninstall/reinstall. Since 10.4 is now available you may want to consider upgrading to that at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your Display Cache?

Comment: @AdamKara  no I have not. I didn't know this was an option. Is this similar to emptying the temp file on a windows computer?

Comment: If you go to Customize>ArcMap Options>Display Cache, you will the amount being currently used and an option to clear the cache.  This will occasionally help me when I'm having issues with the system running slow. Reinstalling is always a good thing to try if you haven't already.